# Restsharp addparameter json For POST does not work

Tags: .net, json, restsharp

I use RestSharp on a REST webservice. I want to send JSON Format to webservice.

This is the json format, I tested it with POSTMAN in google chrome and it works:

```
{
    "boss":[{
    "cus":"454",
    "date":"July 23,2015",
    "mangpo":"9.1",
    "namo":"rattatrayaya"
    },{
    "cus":"872",
    "date":"Feb 23,2015",
    "mangpo":"9.1",
    "namo":"nama Arya Vlokita"
    }]
}
```

This is my code that does not work:

```
 string url = "http://ShiVamSaRaNum/Uma/index.php/create_sudo/Saranung";
        var client = new RestClient(url);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
       request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
       request.AddBody(
           new{
               cus = "454",
               date = "July 23,2015",
               mangpo = "9.1",
               namo = "rattatrayaya"
                });
       RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
       var content = response.Content;
       Console.WriteLine(content.ToString());
       Console.ReadLine();
```

I have tried:

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddObject(jsonObject)
request.Addbody(jsonObject)
```

Comment: Jesus is not gonna help you here my friend. :)

Comment: I had similar issue with RestSharp. I resolved it by switching to HttpClient.